# Get name of anonymous class while inherited process

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming

Is there are any possibility to get `name` of the anonymous class in the inherited, and not raise "fail A"? Should be made through `Class` object creation (no eval or similar).

```
class A
  def self.inherited(base)
    raise 'fail A' unless base.name
  end
end

B = Class.new(A)
# or
Object.const_set :B, Class.new(A)
```

The code above doesn't work, because anonymous class isn't yet initialized so it cannot be set to a specific constant.

Answer (score 5):

No.

An anonymous class doesn’t have a name until it’s been assigned to a constant (e.g. `(B = Class.new).name #=> "B"`). Since assignment does not happen until after the class instance has been created (during which hooks—including `inherited`—are called), there’s no way you can get  the name until afterwards.

Comment: Yep, that's right, but may be there are some hack. I've tried to define `def self.name; 'B'; end` in the block, because I though it will first define the name class method, and then will invoke `inherited`, but no. And for me that behaviour is really strange.

Comment: That doesn’t work because, like above, the hook is called before the block with method definitions is evaluated, so the method doesn’t yet exist.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
class Superclass
  def self.inherited(base)
    raise 'Invalid class name' unless @forced_anonymous_subclass_name == :A
  end
  def self.forced_anonymous_subclass_name
    @forced_anonymous_subclass_name
  end
  def self.with_forced_anonymous_subclass_name(class_name)
    @forced_anonymous_subclass_name = class_name
    yield
  ensure
    @forced_anonymous_subclass_name = nil
  end
end

sc = Superclass

sc.with_forced_anonymous_subclass_name(:A) do
  Object.const_set sc.forced_anonymous_subclass_name, Class.new(sc)
end #=> A

sc.with_forced_anonymous_subclass_name(:B) do
  Object.const_set sc.forced_anonymous_subclass_name, Class.new(sc)
end #=> RuntimeError
```

Feel free to ask if unclear/improvements/etc.

Comment: Hello @mdesantis, what I'm really want to solve is this issue: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb#L189

Your solution will not work, because it checks somewhere in the ActiveSupport code for the `name` method. But I will check to be sure it wont work... maybe you know some cleaner solution?

Comment: Oh... What's the problem with that line? What is the issue you're talking about? If you tell me the problem you're trying to solve we can reason about it; you need to replace the `eval`?

Comment: That's right, I don't know how to replace the `eval` with something more adequate, like `Module.new`.

Comment: And what about `Object.const_set config.controller_name, Class.new(ActiveAdmin::PageController)`? Has it been considered?

Comment: That was the first thing I've tried.

actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:117:in `controller_name': undefined method `demodulize' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: The error you wrote seems to me unrelated to `const_set`... this error doesn't raise up when you use `eval`? It makes me think to an issue of autoloading, but not sure about it

Comment: `const_set` is adding const to the root scope only after the Class will be initialized. The problem that in the `ActiveAdmin::PageController` implementation, it uses `ActionController::Metal` that are trying to get name of the class in a class hook named `included`.

Comment: So the issue is related to `ActionController::Metal` that is not compatible with anonymous classes... I see...

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't think your purpose can be reached. If I was you, I would open a bug to Ruby reporting this missing metaprogramming feature

Comment: I will try to explain everything in a ruby bug tracker, lets look what they say.

At the first sight it looks like class initialization is somewhere here https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L1754

Comment: I don't see what you mean by something "more adequate" than `eval`. `eval` seems to be the definition of adequate in this case.  Perhaps you mean more elegant, but you're talking about an edge case here: basically you want an atomic named-anonymous class init op.  This is not a commonly needed thing, and I think it's the perfect use case for `eval`.  If it bothers you that much then I think the low hanging fruit is to make the inheritable class compatible with anonymous classes, that's probably more justifiable than a new core feature which will take years to become standard enough to rely on.