# What is the difference between class Foo; end & Foo = Class.new (And module/Module)?

Tags: ruby, semantics

I spent a while debugging a problem where I had made a typo of using `Module` instead of `module` to declare a module. Why does Ruby have `module` and `Module` (and similarly `class` and `Class`), with different semantics? See example below:

```
class C; end; # ok
Class C2; end; # error
C3 = class.new # error
C4 = Class.new # ok
```

It seems confusing to have two different constructs which differ only by case.

Comment: `class` is a keyword, `Class` is a class

Comment: “Why is the language this way?” insights (and perhaps even requires) non-factual or speculative answers. Are you instead interested in asking “what are the differences between…?”?

Comment: @NiklasB. And, more broadly, `Class` is just a constant insofar as the syntax is concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class Foo; end` is *roughly* the same as `Foo = Class.new`, but there are some key differences. All of these also hold true for `module Bar; end` vs. `Bar = Module.new`.

- [`class` is a keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000012) whereas [`Class` is simply a constant name](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html) like any other.
- `Class.new` allows creating anonymous (unnamed) classes, whereas `class; end` is a syntax error. This makes the former more useful for metaprogramming.
- `class` creates new lexical scope whereas `Class.new do ... end` does not. E.g.:

  ```
  class Foo; BAR = 42; end
  Baz = Class.new { QUX = 42 }
  BAR       #   NameError: uninitialized constant BAR
  Foo::BAR  #=> 42
  QUX       #=> 42
  Baz::QUX  #=> 42  (warning: toplevel constant QUX referenced by Baz::QUX)
  ```
- Since `Class.new do ... end` is a closure, you can close around local variables. `class ... end` cannot. E.g.

  ```
  foo = 42
  class Foo; puts foo; end  # NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for Foo:Class
  Class.new { puts foo }    # (prints 42)
  ```
- `class` names the class immediately, whereas [`Class.new` does it on assignment (last)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23176229/211563).
- `Class.new` cannot be used to reopen an existing class ([`class_exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-class_exec) or similar must be used), whereas `class Foo; end` reopens `Foo` if it already exists and is a Class.

Besides the functional differences, the keyword syntax is arguably easier to read akin to `{}` vs. `Hash.new` and `[]` vs. `Array.new`.

Answer (score 2):

Class is an object, instance of class
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Class.html

class is a ruby keyword to define a class

```
class Hello
end

Hello.new
```

Comment: You are right that `Class` is an instance of a `Class`, but that does not mean much in this context. It is more relevant to say that `Class` is the class of classes (such as your `Hello`).

Comment: I understand, thanks. However, I have always understood, in most languages, that it is bad practice to have tokens that vary just by case, unless the different cases have the same semantics. Having core constructs that differ only by case seems very confusing (as I said, I spent a few minutes debugging a cryptic error message caused by a typo that used Module instead of module).

Comment: @Anand It is not a bad practice. The cause of the problem is your carelessness. Most Ruby programmers don't confuse `class` with `Class`, or `module` with `Module`. They are spelled the same because they are related. `class` creates a `Class`, `module` creates a `Module`. It is rather confusing if they were spelled differently.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa. I am aware that you use lower case keyword to define a class. It was a typo - that yielded a cryptic error message `undefined keyword_end, expecting end_of_input` (not too helpful). And it took  longer to detect, exactly because the only difference was in the case. If it were more explicit, like module and class_of_modules, that typo would never have happened.

Comment: @Anand you should use a better text editor with syntax highlighting. Also the error is very helpful. It says that the `end` is dangling, which means that at some point you didn't start a context as expected

Comment: Thanks, @NiklasB. I did use TextMate, and it did fail to highlight the capitalized Module, shd have noticed it but didn't - understand the error also better now. Thanks!